# Why do you need to reference the IAM role in the COPY command on Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Regarding using the COPY command for populating a Redshift table with data from S3; I'm wondering if there is a reason for why you have to specify a role via its ARN which provides the permissions even though the Redshift cluster is already associated with that rule. This seems redundant to me but probably there is a reason for this. Hence my question.

This question arose upon reading the [Redshift getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/getting-started.html); specifically regarding steps 2, 3 and 6.

Comment: good question - but i think specifying a rule for redshift cluster does not mean it has to use that, it just allows it to use it. you could still request different security credentials in your redshift copy command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not mandatory to reference an IAM Role when using the COPY command. This is one of several authorization methods available for the cluster to access external resources (e.g. files stored on S3). The reason for specifying the IAM_ROLE clause is to tell Redshift that this is the authorization method to use, you could alternatively specify ACCESS_KEY_ID/SECRET_ACCESS_KEY or CREDENTIALS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html

The reason you need to add the ARN for a *specific* IAM role is that it's possible to add more than one role to a cluster.